# How to find the total price from a list of items in React?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an eCommerce website to React. When a user adds a product in his cart, the state of the cart gets updated. It looks like this -

```
const[cart, setCart] = useState([]);
```

everything works fine, the cart is updated with the help of Firestore. Each item in the cart has properties - **id, image, productName, and productPrice**

I want to display the total price (sum of prices of all the items in the cart). What I try to do is this -

```
const getCartTotal = () => {
    let total = 0;
    {
      cart?.map((item) => total + item.productPrice);
    }
  };
```

But this gives me an error in the browser -

> Line 37:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

What should the correct approach be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cart?`  cart ?  That would mean your expression should be `cart ? thing : else;`, but maybe that's a typo?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: yes that's optional chaining

Comment: wouldn't you want `total += item.productPrice`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `reduce` instead of `map` there.

My solution has both map and reduce for your clarity. You were making some small mistake within map function. You were just returning the `total + item.productPrice` but you were not storing it anywhere.

```
const cart = [
  {
    price: 23,
    id:1
  },
  {
    price: 27,
    id:2
  },
  {
    price: 60,
    id:2
  },
  {
    price: 40,
    id:4
  }
]
function findSumUsingReduce(){

  const s = cart.reduce((s,{price}) => s+price,0)
  return s;
}

function findSumUsingMap(){

  let t = 0;
  cart.map(({price}) => t = t + price)
  return t;
}

const totalUsingReduce = findSumUsingReduce()
const totalUsingMap = findSumUsingMap()

console.log('totalUsingReduce',totalUsingReduce)
console.log('totalUsingMap',totalUsingMap)
```